# Single Post display in wordpress on home page

Tags: wordpress

What I'm trying to do is display a single post in a template that I will use for the home page. I am hoping to do this by flagging it in a category "sticky".

Caveats
1. I am not looking for a simple loop that displays just one of the posts (or am I?).
2. The post will have the standard comments below it to enter new comments.

I guess what I'm looking for is something similar to the "single.php" template, however, grabbing the post with a category, not id....

Answer (score 0):

Create a page instead of a post and configure Wordpress to use that page as the home page (the setting for the assignment is here: `/wp-admin/options-reading.php`).

You can then assign a custom template to that page and it will always be the page users see first when they come to front door of the site.

Will there be different posts that will appear on this front page? You can always create a custom query in the page template to grab the most recent post in the 'sticky' category, or by whatever criteria you're using.

Comment: It's the query I'm looking for. I understand the basics, however, am getting stuck with the coding